# How to search tilde in url, using google syntax?

Tags: search, search-engine

I know, that inurl command will search within url, but tilde (~) is special symbol.

However, I want to find it inside url.

For example, `find address domain.com/~books`

Comment: What do you mean by `google syntax` and could you please be more clear. This is a very vague question. To check for a tilde you could use following function: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/aq7dka5z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search) at Webbapps.SE says:

> Unfortunately, this is not possible.
>
> From the official [Google Help Page](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=134479):
>
> > Generally, punctuation is ignored, including @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters

Comment: but tilde ~ is not a special character, you can search it in the search box. In the mean time, tilde immediately before the search item means to search its  synonyms

Comment: @PhilChang Not any more! http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2013/06/googles-tilde-operator-no-longer-works.html